# How to set Wix to do a HTTP request upon an event

Tags: javascript, velo

I have a Wix site and I have this JS code in the site:

```
import { fetch } from 'wix-fetch';

$w("#button1").onClick( (event) => {
    var link = $w("#link").id;
    console.log(link)
      fetch("https://my-new-app-xyz.herokuapp.com?link="+link, {"method": 'get'})
.then((httpResponse) => {
    if (httpResponse.ok) {
        return httpResponse;
    } else {
        return Promise.reject("Failed");
    }
} )
.catch( (err) => {
    console.log(err);
  } );
})
```

However, upon the click of `button1` nothing happens. Hopefully, the code explains what I want to do, but, upon clicking `button1`. I want to get the value of the text box element with id `link` and send a GET request to `"https://my-new-app-xyz.herokuapp.com?link="` + the link from the text box. I don't know much JavaScript - this code is from reading the Wix API docs.

Comment: What would you like to do with the response? Change an element in your site?

Comment: The response will return a video and I'd like it to either be downloaded or to be shown on the site like it does on the API I have made: [here](https://youtube-2-mp3.herokuapp.com/api/v1/videos?link=https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9bZkp7q19f0). If opened on Chrome there are 3 dots of which one is a Download option. @AdamMatan

Comment: Why not use the built-in video player with the original youtube URL, and a link to the heroku app below it? https://www.wix.com/corvid/reference/$w/videoplayer/src

Comment: @AdamMatan, I want the user to be able to download the video. So, I want to send a GET request to the site which will then download the video, or alternatively to open in a new tab the link (less preferred).

Comment: Got it. You have an origin file at heroku, and your user needs to download it. No need to save it in your wix site in between; simply provide [a download link](https://www.wix.com/corvid/forum/community-discussion/how-to-link-text-to-a-url-using-w-link) for the user, and present the video snippet using the wix video player.